# How does the "not" operator work in this function?

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-operator

I am having trouble understanding how this function returns true or false depending on whether num is divisible of 100. The "not" operator is what is throwing me off.

```
    function divisible(num) {
    return !(num % 100)
}
```

I wrote the function this way:

```
    function divisible(num) {
    return num % 100 === 0 ? true : false;
}
```

This first solution looks much cleaner and I would like to understand how it works.

Comment: If num%100 == 0, and you negate it, it becomes 1, so true, else if you negate anything else 0, so false

Comment: have a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: That is a nasty use of `!`. I understand you are asking in general how `!` works, but in the example, `return num % 100 !== 0` is really much more readable.

Comment: It's personal preference whether one prefers `!(num % 100)` or `num % 100 !== 0`, but adding `? true : false` after either (or any Boolean expression) is horribly redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, `0` (zero) is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), which makes `!0` (not zero) [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

From [MDN docs on falsiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

> A falsy (sometimes written falsey) value is a value that is considered false when encountered in a Boolean context.

> JavaScript uses type conversion to coerce any value to a Boolean in contexts that require it, such as conditionals and loops.

So in your case these are equivalent:

```js
return num % 100 === 0 ? true : false;
return num % 100 === 0;  // ternary not necessary; expression already evaluates to a boolean
return !(num % 100) // zero is falsy; negate to reverse it
```

Comment: The falsiness of 0 would actually make `!0` true, not truthy, since `!` is a boolean operator and its result is a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

`a == 0` and `!a` are equivalent in JavaScript since 0 is Falsy and when applying a boolean operator like `!` on it it will be treated as `false`. Thus, `!(x % y)` evaluates to `true` only when the remainder of integer division is `0` as all other integer values are truthy.

Comment: …iff `a` is a number and not `NaN`.

Answer (score -1):

Note that in JS, `0` stands for `falsy` and every other non-null numeric value corresponds to `truthy`, ***"in boolean context"***.
If the `num` is divisible by 100, then `num%100` would equate to `0`
And negation of `0` i.e `!(0)` is `1` which means `true, the number is perfectly divisible by 100`.
Otherwise if the `num%100` gives a value other than `0`, and negation of `<anything other than 0>` is `0`, which corresponds to `false, the number is not completely divisible by 100`

Comment: "every other value corresponds to true", that's not entirely correct, empty strings, null, undefined and NaN would also correspond to false

Comment: Oh a rookie mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. Corrected it.